# unable to send email via smtp over ssl

Tags: ruby, email, ssl, rubygems, smtp

i am writing a ruby script to send email using 'mail' gem.

and my smtp settings on my local machine:

```
mailer_options:
    address: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    domain: gmail.com
    user_name: example@gmail.com
    password: example_password
    authentication: :login
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    ssl: true
```

when i try to send the email with the above smtp settings i get the following exception:---

`/opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:585:in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

i tried installing ssl certificate by command

openssl s_client -connect gmail.com:443

but it does not help, thanks for any comments and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 587 starts out plain text, and then "upgrades" to ssl via `starttls` if you want smtp from the start to use ssl, then you need to use port 465.

so either of these should fix your issue.

Remove `enable_starttls_auto` and set the port to `465`

or

Remove `ssl: true` and rely on `starttls` to upgrade your connection to ssl

Comment: that would do it as well, the `enable_starttls_auto` is just extra at that point as the smtp server shouldn't offer since it is already encrypted.

Comment: `Remove ssl: true and rely on starttls to upgrade your connection to ssl` that it is!!!